# Using 'amodem' to transfer digitally using a UV5R

Tags: digital-modes, vhf, uhf, packet

I reviewed [docs](https://github.com/romanz/amodem/blob/master/README.rst) for amodem, and it looks like I can send files and possibly other things with this.

I should only need to prep my computer as per the doc and set VOX correctly. Does anyone have experience with this software, or a recommendation for something better (linux/bsd)?

Comment: What is your **precise** question?

Comment: Is amodem the right way to go to play with packet, before investing in a real TNC, or are there better routes?

Comment: Amodem works very well for my needs. This question is no longer active. I can push 3-4KB/s after adjusting mic/spkr levels with `amodem {send,recv} --calibrate`. Only tried peer-to-peer, not over repeaters, which is likely frowned upon for this kind of tomfoolery anyway.

Comment: @user400344 Why don't you post that as an answer and accept it? If you don't, the question will coninue to be automatucally bumped up, since there are no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amodem works very well for my needs. This question is no longer active. I can push 3-4KB/s after adjusting mic/spkr levels with amodem {send,recv} --calibrate. Only tried peer-to-peer, not over repeaters, which is likely frowned upon for this kind of tomfoolery anyway.